# How to execute script in Espruino runtime from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, espruino

How to execute the script from string const in Espruino runtime from NodeJS?

I have a script in const or variable:

`const espruinoScript =` 
console.log("Hello");
`;`

I'm would like to execute the script like this:
espruino.executeScript(espruinoScript);

I don't want to send to hardware device.